# Storing a grid of results in excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I work at a dry cleaning place, and we are going to send out a survey to ask our customers what they don't like about garments we've dry cleaned for them, so we know what to improve on. I need to record the feedback into an excel spreadsheet, and I need a little help.

This is what the survey looks like

[image]

So for each type of garment, they are asked to check which factors (odor, shrinkage, feel, cleanliness) they didn't like. So in the example above, customer #431 thought that his suit jacket shrunk, and it wasn't clean. His suit pants were fine. His wool sweater didn't smell good. Etc.

Now I need to record the data into an excel sheet. Ideally I'd like to have a row for each customer, and then some how record all the data in the following columns. But I'd like it to be in a way that I can easily extract data from the sheet. So when it gets to be hundreds of customers long, I can run a function somewhere else that will tell me, for example, how many suit jackets shrunk. Or what percentage of garments weren't clean. Etc.

I don't have a lot of experience with excel, so I'm getting a little stuck. This is a very simplified example of what I'm looking for:

[image]

But I don't like that approach because you would have to have multiple rows for each customer for each garment. And there isn't really a way to include multiple factors for each garment.

Hope that makes sense. How would you go about this problem?

Comment: The site focuses on specific hardware and software problems for which there is a right answer. This kind of conceptual problem isn't a good fit.  That aside, my recommendation would be not to do this without input from people with some survey and marketing expertise. How you frame this, who you ask, what you ask, and how you ask it drive the results, and your survey could backfire. e.g., asking people if there was a cleanliness problem will raise warning flags in customers who never thought there could be one.  Focusing on quality improvement is great, but there are good and bad ways to do it.

Comment: I have to agree with @fixer1234 here. Nevertheless to answer the question from a practical point of view, I've given an answer.

Comment: But I would indeed make the questions be positive, with the option to add a complaint: For example: How was the service? 1-10, How clean were your clothes 1-10 Was there something you'd like to mention?.....

Comment: I see your issue. It took me a while to figure out that "Database" is the better instrument to learn. If you put in the time you can really do really intricate things with a database. The best way in excel is to do what you are already doing because of the nature of information. Customer and Garment will be repeated for this customer, but that's what you want. Why? Because later you'll want to "Query" your data which will look like this in Excel: Filter Customer 431, or Filter Garments, Shrinkage. It's redundant yes, but that's data. Data is raw, but you need raw data to perform queries.

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for your help. I came here to make this question, because on StackOverflow it says "General help regarding MS Excel for single worksheet functions is available at Super User." I greatly simplified the reasons we're conducting the survey and how we're going to use the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Keep doing what you are doing** as I've noted in my comment.

**Step 1**: Here is a minor modification that will help you in your **Data Entry**: see **image.2** for setting up your data for success.

Note: The usage of **=vlookup()** values in list-tables to the right. This alleviates spelling errors which causes errors in queries later when you want to do analysis on your data.

**Step 2**: See image.1. Make sure you have Developers Tab, enabled.
File, Options, Customize Ribbon, check the box "Developer"

**Step 3**: See image.1. Enable Forms! Like Step 1. File, Options, Customize Ribbon. Change the drop down "Choose Commands from", to "Commands Not in the Ribbon". Scroll down and look for "Form...". Click on Forms. Click on Developer Tab on the right as well. Then in the middle click on "Add>>"

---

image.1
[image]

---

**Step 4**: See image.2. Use the form to enter new "records". Select your records, Developer's Tab > Forms. Click Form. Enter new record.

---

image.2
[image]

Final Note: Now that your data is more "data entry friendly", you can enter new records with ease. Data integrity is important to analyze data correctly via queries/filters. A query on data provides useful information about data that can be analyzed.

A side note for future endeavors in data management and analysis: For advanced data entry a database is very powerful. MS Access is one of such database management tools. A Form can be created on data (tables). Queries can analyze data and built into said forms.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there are only 5 pieces of clothes you are registereing? But you could limit the factors down to 1 letter: O, S, F and C, put all the garment + customer as a row, and register it as follows:

```
Customer | Suit Jacket | Suit Pants | Wool Sweater | Dress | Skirt |
431      | S,C         | none       | O            | F     | O,S,C |
```

Alternatively, the Suit Pants could have been empty too. Probably looks cleaner.

Once this is done, you can apply a filter to the list, and make it only show cells where the text contains a C.

Comment: Yeah there are indeed a lot more items of clothing, and a lot more factors. I just simplified it for the example. But I suppose that could work. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I figured that was the case, otherwise you might have been able to create a column for every possible situation, and note a 1 if the case was true. But if you have lots of clothes and lots of factors, that is not gonna work. Of course with many factors you can reduce them to 2 or 3 letters as easily, just make sure you are consistent. Numbers would work too, but will make it hard to read it back.